# how to keep perforce changelist number consistent

Tags: perforce

I am new to perforce. A weird behaviour of perforce is causing quite a bit of trouble. My original repo (the one that pushes to remote server) has

```
p4 changes
Change 3 on 2017/06/23 by user@user-dvcs-1498104674 'add test-copy.go'
Change 2 on 2017/06/23 by user@user-dvcs-1498104674 'add test.go'
Change 1 on 2017/06/22 by user@user-dvcs-1498104674 '"first sub repo" '
```

but my cloned repo (a newly created folder to make a clone from remote server) has

```
p4 changes
Change 6 on 2017/06/23 by user@user-dvcs-1498104674 'add test-copy.go'
Change 5 on 2017/06/23 by user@user-dvcs-1498104674 'add test.go'
Change 4 on 2017/06/22 by user@user-dvcs-1498104674 '"first sub repo" '
```

does anyone have a good idea to get around this when the resource action is to checkout a particular commit?
This is causing a problem when my colleague create a clone of my repo we reference to the same commit with the changelist number, whereas in git a commit sha is consistent across server and different clones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `submit.identity` configurable to set global IDs on changelists that will be preserved across servers:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/manuals/dvcs/fetching.changelists.html#fetching.track_identity

Comment: I set that in my local server.
```
any: P4LOG = p4_log.txt
any: db.monitor.shared = 0
any: dm.user.noautocreate = 1
any: journalPrefix = backups/back
any: monitor = 3
any: server = 0
any: server.allowfetch = 3
any: server.allowpush = 1
any: server.allowrewrite = 1
any: submit.identity = uuid
```
but after I push it to the remote server(perforce public server) then clone it. The cloned changes list is not consistent with my local change list. 
eg. local repo changelist ID: 1,2,3  and cloned repo changelist ID 4,5,6

Comment: The "Identity" is different from the changelist number.